# Bot won't respond to Emoji Reaction

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I'm planning to make a bot that got Name and Birthday from User input, and before storing the user's answer to database (in my case, Google Spreadsheet via `gspread`), Ask the user that input is correct.

So I decided to show an react emojis bottom the Checking embed, and If user reacts with ⭕, It will append the User's input to Google Spreadsheet. in the other hand, if user reacts with ❌ one, It discard the user input and Showing Error Message.

[The bot works.... only the Checking Embed. how nice.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UUnnH.png)
and yes, bot deployed with no error, and If I use slash command and input the Data, the Bot prints Checking Embed and React Emojis well. (Look at the Picture for result.)

But It didn't react when I responded emoji. both of all not work.

here's my code about that command.

```
@slash.slash(
    name="테스트쓰기",
    description="샘플 데이터를 구글 시트에 작성합니다.",
    guild_ids=[865433__________],
    options=[
        create_option(
            name="이름",
            description="스프레드시트에 표시될 이름",
            option_type=3,
            required=True
        ),
        create_option(
            name="생일",
            description="MM-DD 형식으로 입력",
            option_type=3,
            required=True
        )
    ],
    connector={
    '이름': 'uname',
    '생일': 'btday'
    }
)
async def ap_sheet(ctx:SlashContext, uname:str, btday:str):
    checker = await ctx.send(embed=check_emb(ctx, uname=uname, btday=btday))
    
    await checker.add_reaction("⭕")
    await checker.add_reaction("❌")

    async def check(reaction, user):
        return user == ctx.user and reaction.message.id == checker.id and str(reaction.emoji) in ['⭕','❌']
        
        while True : 
            try:
                reaction, user = await bot.wait_for("reaction_add", check=check, wait_for=20.0) #Wait 20sec for user input
                
                if str(reaction.emoji) == '⭕': #User Accepts and wants to append data to sheet
                    await checker.delete()
                    await ctx.send(discord.Embed(title="완료", description="입력한 정보를 내보냈습니다.", color=discord.Color.blue()), delete_after=5)
                    gc1.append_row([uname, ctx.author.id, btday])
                    
                elif str(reaction.emoji) == '❌': #User Cancels command
                    await checker.delete()
                    await ctx.send(discord.Embed(title="취소됨!", description="사용자의 조작에 의해 취소되었어요.", color=discord.Color.red()), delete_after=5)
    
                pass
            
            except asyncio.TimeoutError: #Time is Over
                await ctx.send("시간 초과되었습니다.")
```

Comment: `check` is never called/registered?

Comment: ^ check your indentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the proper way to call a check, it doesnt look like yours is ever called

```py
answers = ["⭕","❌"]
    for reaction in answers:
        await ctx.message.add_reaction(emoji=reaction)

 def check(reaction, user):
        if str(reaction.emoji) in answers and user.id == ctx.author.id:
            return user == ctx.author and str(reaction.emoji) == str(reaction.emoji)

try:
    reaction, user = await bot.wait_for('reaction_add', timeout=20.0, check=check)
    if(str(reaction)=="❌"):
        #Deny code here, I would recommend deleting the prompt
    if(str(reaction)=="⭕"):
        #Confirm code here
except:
    #Code will go here if there is a timeout. I would recommend deleting the prompt
```

Comment: Thanks for the Solution! after re-write the code with your solution, The bot works and respond on Emoji react, but It always react as timeout(code in ```except:```), not showing proper respond(in ```try:```).

Comment: @BlacK.CHi change `except` to `except Exception as e` and then add `raise e` to the exception block, whats the error that is thrown when the block is run now?

Answer (score 0):

Oh, you have an indentation mistake in your `while` loop. Your `while` loop is inside your reaction `check` function.